# Запускается сразу два таймера обратного отсчета, не могу понять почему?

Tags: javascript

```js
createGame(createRandomArr(createArr(5)), 5);

// основная функция которая запускает все другие функции
function createGame(arrElem, numLeng) {
  var table = document.querySelector("table");


  var num1 = 0;
  var num2 = 0;

  createTableElem(arrElem, table, num1, numLeng);
  styleRed(table, num2, numLeng);
  buttonElem();
};

// функция, при клике на кнопку запускается обратный счет 
function buttonElem() {
  var button = document.querySelector("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    timer();
  });
}
// создаю массив
function createArr(numElem) {
  numElem = numElem * numElem;
  var arr = [];

  for (var i = 1; i <= numElem; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  };
  return arr;
};
// создаю массив из случайных чисел
function createRandomArr(arrElem) {
  var arr = [];

  while (arr.length < arrElem.length) {
    var num = getRandomInt(1, arrElem.length);
    if (arr.indexOf(num) == -1) {
      arr.push(num);
    };
  };
  return arr;
};

// выводит случайное число
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};


// функция создает элементы с цифрами для таблицы 
function createTableElem(arrElem, tableElem, numElem, numLeng) {
  for (var i = 0; i < numLeng; i++) {

    var tr = document.createElement("tr");

    for (var j = numElem; j < numElem + numLeng; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = arrElem[j];
      tr.appendChild(td);
    };

    numElem += numLeng;
    tableElem.appendChild(tr);
  };
}
// функция при клике на один из элементов таблицы перекрашивает в красный цвет
function styleRed(tableElem, numElem, numLeng) {

  var td = tableElem.querySelectorAll("td");
  for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    td[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var arr = createArr(numLeng);
      if (arr[numElem] == Number(this.innerHTML)) {
        this.style.background = "red";
        numElem += 1;
      };

      if (numElem == arr.length) {
        var p = document.querySelector("p");
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        p.innerHTML = "40 сек";

        tableElem.innerHTML = "";
        numElem = 0;
        numLeng += 1;
        createGame(createRandomArr(createArr(numLeng)), numLeng);
      };
    });
  };
};


// функция таймер обратный отсчет 
function timer() {
  intervalID = setInterval(funcc, 1000);
  console.log(intervalID);
};
// функция обратный отсчет 
function funcc() {
  var p = document.querySelector("p");
  var table = document.querySelector("table");

  p.innerHTML = parseInt(p.innerHTML) - 1 + " сек";

  if (parseInt(p.innerHTML) == 0) {
    console.log(intervalID);
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    console.log(intervalID);
    p.innerHTML = "10 сек";

    table.innerHTML = "";
    numElem = 0;
    createGame(createRandomArr(createArr(5)), 5);
  };
};
```

```html
<table border="1">
</table>
<button>Старт</button>
<p>10 сек</p>
```

При клике запускаю обратный отсчет. После того как отсчет закончился, при повторном нажатие отсчет начинает запускать сразу 2 таймера, не могу понять почему. При том что после того как обратный отсчет до ходит до нуля, отменяю обратный отсчет через clearInterval.

Comment: в функе `createGame` у вас есть вызов функи `buttonElem` которая вешает на кнопку хендлер (где создаеться таймер), игру вы пересоздаете, тоесть функа `buttonElem` вызываеться снова, и снова вешаеться хендлер, попробуйте удалять хендлер клика на кнопку при создании игры

Comment: Он запускается один раз, только вывод два раза `console.log(intervalID)` в `funn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При пересоздании игры вы каждый раз вешаете хендлер клика на кнопку в итоге он попросту вызываеться несколько раз.

Нужно ето :

```
function buttonElem() {
  var button = document.querySelector("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    timer();
  });
}
```

заменить на ето :

```
function buttonElem() {
  var button = document.querySelector("button");
  button.removeEventListener("click", timer);
  button.addEventListener("click", timer);
}
```

Ну или же думать вариант как не пересоздавать игру, а перезапускать или чтото в етом духе.

Comment: @КамранРаджабов незачто, если ответ вам помог/подошел, на СО принято отмечать галкой(возле голосов), как правильный, чтобы закрыть данный топик